# Complex coutif formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I hava a dataset that on the headers has: (String Employee Name, String Day off, time Check-in, time Check-out).

What I want to do is get a table that has row labels from Monday through Friday, and as column titles, hours from 00:00 to 23:00. In each cell of that table I should have the number of employees who are working that day at that hour (i.e., the count of employees whose shift includes that hour and are not in their day off).

There are no partial hours, all employees work whole hours.  Every employee gets a single day off.

I've tried with array formulas, countifs, etc. But I don't seem to be getting any closer to a real solution.

Comment: How do you handle partial hours (actual time that occurs within the time window?  round to nearest whole hour?  full hour if present during that hour?)

Comment: No employee works partial hours and, sadly, have only one day off—including myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have done it. Here is how --

First, I extended your dataset to make life easier. So after the first 4 columns add columns headed (starting E1) "00:00", "01:00" ... "23:00". For the first employee in "00:00" (cell E2) put the formula

```
=IF(AND(E$1>=$C2, E$1<=$D2),1,0)
```

This should show a 1 if the person is working that hour, and a zero if they are not, by comparing the column heading to the in/out times. Copy-fill the formula across to the other hours, then down for all the employees.

Now, to make life easier for myself I made the totals table (ie what you are after), with the hours directly aligned under these new columns on the same sheet. In my sample data I went to row 5 for the employee data, so you need to adjust this to how many rows you have. In the Monday total row, for cell in column E (0:00) use the formula

```
=SUMIFS(E$2:E$5,$B$2:$B$5,"<>Monday")
```

This should total the 1's above only if they are not working on Monday at 0:00. Copy-fill the formula down 4 more cells, and simply change the day at the end of the formula to Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday. Add the row labels from Monday through Friday to the left of these cells.

Finally, copy-fill this formula (the 5 cells) across to populate the entire total table (ie to 23:00 column). In the end it is not too complex and easy to check it is doing what you expect I think. It is all dynamic, change the in/out times or the day off and the total table will reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something similar to your approach. On a hidden table I did